# How can I find datas smaller than "this sunday" in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, datetime

I have a mysql table and a date colomb that show when I add datas...

I wanna select datas smallar than this sunday from table..

HOw can I do that_? here is my code...

I couldnt figure it out "sevk_tarihi < DAY(3)"...

```
foreach($baglanti->query('SELECT SUM(sistem_adedi),sevk_tarihi FROM
databasename WHERE  (sistem_tipi_data="CEDRUS" 
or  sistem_tipi_data="PINO"
or sistem_tipi_data="BOSSO" 
or sistem_tipi_data="JUNIPER"
or sistem_tipi_data="OLIVA" 
or sistem_tipi_data="CARPE" 
or sistem_tipi_data="SELVI" 
or sistem_tipi_data="AINE" 
or sistem_tipi_data="SEKOYA" 
or sistem_tipi_data="DAPHNE" 
or sistem_tipi_data="WILLOW" 
or sistem_tipi_data="SEKOYA" )
and (sevk_tarihi < DAY(3)) ' )   as $row)
```

Comment: considering your'e generating this query inside of javascript, I would also consider writing your code for `"this sunday"` inside of javascript, rather than implementing the logic via SQL.

Comment: write a function called `getThisSunday()` which outputs the date, either as a Date object or in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

Comment: getThisSunday()  doesnt help..

Comment: Tip: `WHERE sistem_tipi_dat IN ("CEDRUS", PINO", ..., "SEKOYA") ...`

Comment: @haluk you're supposed to create the function, haha, not just write `getThisSunday()` and hope it works

Comment: Jarlh sorry but that code doesnt work.. I tried it before than I do code like that.. thanks for advice

Comment: TkoL yes I am looking for "getThisSunday()" code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, I misunderstood the question

This gives you past sunday

```
set @date = curdate() ;
SELECT @date - interval weekday(@date) + 1 DAY;
```

this gives you next sunday

```
set @date = curdate();
SELECT @date + interval 6 - weekday(@date) day;
```

for your query

```
sevk_tarihi < curdate() + interval 6 - weekday(curdate()) day
```

gives you this sunday

Comment: sunday = 6 or 0 ?

Comment: `weekday` returns 0 for Monday, etc.

Comment: ( sevk_tarihi BETWEEN  current_date - interval weekday(current_date) + 1 DAY  AND  current_date() + interval 6 - weekday(current_date()) day)')

Comment: this shows me all project in this week... the mistak in your code is "not curdate" it is current_date".. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

To compute the date of the last Sunday, you can offset the current date by `dayofweek() - 1` day, like so:

```
current_date - interval (dayofweek(current_date) - 1) day
```

`dayofweek()` returns `1` on Sunday, `2` and Monday, and so on.

Comment: so everyday I need to change code? to see smaller than this sunday? :)

Comment: @haluk: no. This expression dynamically computes the date of last Sunday based on the current date.

Comment: it means "1" = the monday of  the week that include "current_date"  ?

Comment: @haluk: I don't understand your question. This expression gives you date of the last Sunday, which is how I understood your question. Please try it. you can change `current_date` to some literal date to understand how this behaves.

Comment: this is this saturday.. what about last saturday?
So I will try t between 2 dates so I can see excat work or not.. Thanks